# Pptp port forward mikrotik

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, port, pptp, mikrotik

I am connected to a pptp server(mikrotik). My client is outside the local network of the mikrotik. I want to use my client to host a media server which I want to be forwarded through the mikrotik router to the internet. What do I do to make this happen? Completely a newbie in this case.

Comment: Standard warning for all PPTP posts: PPTP's security was compromised long ago and it has been deprecated for more than a decade by its creator, Microsoft. Any VPNs still using PPTP should be transitioned to a more modern that's actually secure.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you mean by “which I want to be forwarded through the mikrotik router to the internet”? Do you perhaps want to set up a port forwarding on the Mikrotik router, to the PPTP client host? // Port forwarding over VPN is tricky, because return traffic must be sent over the VPN.